# How is the gate charge of a MOS transistor used in real designs?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design

From LTspice you could get information about gate charge of a MOS transistor as in the image below.

How is this information used in real design? Do you usually use this information in your design?

[image]

Comment: The higher the gate charge, the harder it is to drive the MOSFET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very important parameter especially in applications like power supplies. The lower the number, the faster the mosfet will turn on and off given the gate resistor and voltage applied are the same.

An example of how I use the gate charge and apply into usable information is I convert it into a capacitance and can then calculate the approximate rise and fall time of the gate based on an RC time constant.

Example:

Qg = 50nC

Gate Drive Voltage = 15V

Gate Resistor = 10ohm

You use the charge formula Q = CV. 50nC = C * 15
Solve for C and you get 3.33nF of capacitance. Now that you know the capacitance, you can take the RC time constant of the gate resistor and the capacitance and get a rise/ fall time.

10ohm * 3.333nF = 33nS

I use this to get me a ballpark idea of what to expect. Then I'll design around that number giving plenty of room for margin and then tweak the circuit in real life to get the rise and fall times that I want by changing the gate resistor value.